# How to secure database credentials present in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, password-protection

How do I secure connection credentials which are used in `config/database.yml`. How do I secure username, password, host information for my db settings.

```
local: &local
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  username: foo
  password: bar
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. At some point you have to put this stuff in and it has to be in plaintext.

This is usually a problem during deployment where you don't want anyone with read access to the repository to see your deployment servers db configuration.

I worked around that by having a custom capistrano task that copies (or symlinks) a database.yml from the server's home directory into the app.
(So in my repo there is a blank database.yml and it gets overridden whenever I publish a new version by the secret version that's already present on the server)

I wrote about this here: 
http://www.tigraine.at/2011/09/25/securely-managing-database-yml-when-deploying-with-capistrano/

As for not sharing this while developing: Simply put database.yml into your .gitignore and it won't get committed

Comment: Wouldn't symlinking config files be a better solution then copying them every time?